# splashscreen not closing properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, screen, splash-screen

I'm having some strange problem which I cannot resolve by my self... I have created splash screen (Form3 ~ SplashScreen) using thread, somehow after the application gets to the part

> thread.Abort();

(which actually kills the thread) splash screen stays on the screen until I move mouse on it, or click it somewhere on other form (for instance Form1)... I'm becoming more confused because, this doesn't happen in VS when I run application. The the splash screen is closing properly..., it only happens on the compiled .exe 
Program.cs

```
     namespace ICAMReports
 {
     static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
 }
```

SplashScreen.cs

```
    namespace ICAMReports
{
    public partial class SplashScreen : Form
    {
        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Increment(1);
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
    namespace ICAMReports
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(splashScreen));
            th.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            th.Abort();
        }
        public void splashScreen()
        {
            Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
        }
       //this where the rest of code is placed....
    }
}
```

Any clue, why is this happening or how to fix this?

screenshot:[image: Splashscreen not closing after Form1 is loaded...]

Comment: I don't know how you can have `thread.Abort` and "closing properly" in the same question

Comment: thread.Abort is actually th.Abort(); in the Form1.cs

Comment: As I understood; Thread.Sleep(3000); -> stops the current thread, and th.Abort(); -> kills the thread (and therefore closing the SplashScreen form...) correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: thread sleep puts the thread to sleep, and then thread abort may close the form but its doing it unnaturally

Comment: ok, but if it closes form, how come the splash screen is still on the screen..., so long until: (I press the key on keyboard or click on the splash screen or another form), it looks like it is still in the memory... (Please refer to the picture that I uploaded)

Comment: because you aren't handling it anywhere near correctly.. take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN says concerning thread.Abort, "Calling this method usually terminates the thread."

There is a countless number of ways you can close out your Splash Screen without using thread.Abort.

Here is one such way to accomplish what it appears you are trying to do.

SplashScreen.cs

```
    namespace ICAMReports
{
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    ManualResetEventSlim splashDone;
    public SplashScreen(ManualResetEventSlim SplashDone)
    {
     splashDone=SplashDone;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            splashDone.Set();
            this.Close();
        } } } }
```

Form1.CS

```
      namespace ICAMReports
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ManualResetEventSlim splashDone = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(splashScreen));
        th.Start();
        splashDone.Wait();
    }
    public void splashScreen()
    {
        Application.Run(new SplashScreen(splashDone));
    }
   //this where the rest of code is placed....
    }
    }
```

splashDone.Wait() will accomplish the same thing you were trying to do with the Sleep() but instead you should use your loading Bar in your Splash Screen to tell you when to end the thread. Actually in this scenario it really doesn't make any sense to have the splash Screen on a separate thread because the sleep/wait will pause the main form from loading anything until the Splash Screen is finished. Suppose you had resource intensive things in your Form1 that you wanted to load while the Splash Screen is distracting the user. You would do something like this instead of just pausing the Form1 entirely(since the entire point of using a separate thread is that they both run simultaneously.

SplashScreen.cs

```
    namespace ICAMReports
{
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    Form parent;
    delegate void show();
    public SplashScreen(Form Parent)
    {
     parent=Parent;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            parent.Invoke(new show(()=>{parent.Opacity=100;}));
            this.Close();
        } } } }
```

Form1.CS

```
      namespace ICAMReports
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(splashScreen));
        th.Start();
        this.Opacity=0;
    }
    public void splashScreen()
    {
        Application.Run(new SplashScreen(this));
    }
   //this where the rest of code is placed....
    }
    }
```

edit: Responding to loading bar animation

The loading bar will move and look different depending on the version and settings of Windows you are using. You can't use a Thread.Sleep to let the loading bar catch up because it pauses the loadingBar1 animation. You need to give your loading bar about ~10% to catch up(adjust it as needed) this should fix your problem of the loading bar animation.

```
    int i = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(i++<100)progressBar1.Value++;
        if (i == 110)
        {
         splashDone.Set();
         this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the first code worked, it fixed closing the splash screen (form), but for some reason, progressbar1 doesn't go to 100, it closes form in approx at 75%...

Comment: You need to let the timer go over a few more ticks to allow the animation to finish updating. I edited my post above to give you one possible solution. Just create a separate variable that can go above the max progressBar1 value and exit out when that equals 110 or whatever time gap you want to insure the loading bar animation finishes. I tested the above 110 setting above and it gives the animation plenty of time to finish. If you need it to last longer increase the number if you want it to go a little faster 105 just barely makes it to the end.

Comment: thanks CodeCamper, even though I don't understand why the previous code didn't work..., and why do I need to set value above 100...

Comment: Thread.Abort does not close the Thread it only sends a signal to the Thread that it should close. For a countless number of reasons the Thread may never get the signal or get it much later than you would expect. Perhaps because no event is being raised the form never realizes the signal until some event is raised such as the mouse move event. You are not setting the value of the loading bar above 100 the reason you must set a second value above 100 is to give your loading bar animation some time to finish loading because the default windows 7/8 loading animation has a delay built in.

Comment: Thanks CodeCamper, sorry for bugging you with such a simple code..., I'm new in C# and currently learning that programming language, again your code help me to achieve what I wanted, and help me understand how to do it... Big thanks for the help...! Cheers.

Comment: Anytime! Ironically the thing that confused me the most was that loading bar. I never noticed it before and I tried to use Thread.Sleep to give the loading bar some time to load but that didn't work because it froze the thread that the loading bar was loading on. I recommend trying out the second way I posted too as that way will actually allow your main form to load and process as the splash screen does its fake loading because if you pause the main form with the ManualResetEvent or Sleep as you did originally it will stop the form from loading while the Splash Screen is up. Glad to help!